# Using Oauth with YouTube api

Tags: api, oauth, youtube, localhost

I am trying to add OAuth athentication with to access YouTube, but how do I add localhost as domain?

For example on domain registration page [here](https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains), I want to use localhost, since I am developing this application locally.

Please help me or suggest me alternative ways

Thank you

P.S. I also added this question on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/, but not sure about community activity there so please ignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you can't register 'localhost' for authentication since it is merely an alias. If you want to use OAuth with any Google service, you'll have to have a domain. If you're developing a desktop app, there is a workaround (this may actually work for all but I didn't try):

You can actually sign your OAuth requests without registering your domain with Google by creating a signature using HMAC-SHA1, a consumer key of "anonymous" and a consumer secret of "anonymous".  Just make sure you have the appropriate signature base string for your requests.

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#SigningOAuth

Answer (score 0):

On the page in Google's APIs console where you provide redirect URIs for your app, you can use localhost. Or you can give another name to localhost in your `/etc/hosts` file like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost myname.madeupdomain.net
```